# Bootstrap breaks calendarextender formatting

Tags: c#, twitter-bootstrap

I have created the responsive form. When I clicked on start date, calender box is not coming properly. Why it is happening?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/4qEXj.png

Code:

```
<div class="row">
                       <div class="form-group">
                         <div class="col-sm-2"></div>
                          <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="Start date">Start Date:</label>
                         <div class="col-sm-8">
                             <asp:TextBox ID="DateFromtxt" runat="server" Width="50px" MaxLength="10" CssClass="form-control" style="width:50%;"></asp:TextBox>
                             <ajaxToolkit:CalendarExtender ID="CalendarExtender1" runat="server" 
                                            TargetControlID="DateFromtxt" Format="yyyy-MM-dd">
                             </ajaxToolkit:CalendarExtender>
                             <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator17" runat="server" 
                                            ControlToValidate="DateFromtxt" ErrorMessage="* Start date Required" 
                                            Display="Dynamic"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                             <asp:CustomValidator ID="CustomValidator1" runat="server" ErrorMessage="* Enter Valid Date"
                                        TargetControlID="DateFromtxt"
                                         Display="Dynamic"></asp:CustomValidator> 
                           <br />
                       </div>
                </div>
                  </div>

                   <div class="row">
                       <div class="form-group">
                         <div class="col-sm-2"></div>
                          <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="End date">End Date:</label>
                         <div class="col-sm-8">
                             <asp:TextBox ID="DateTotxt" runat="server" Width="50px" MaxLength="10" CssClass="form-control" style="width:50%;"></asp:TextBox>
                             <ajaxToolkit:CalendarExtender ID="CalendarExtender2" runat="server" 
                                            TargetControlID="DateTotxt" Format="yyyy-MM-dd">
                             </ajaxToolkit:CalendarExtender>
                             <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator16" runat="server" 
                                            ControlToValidate="DateTotxt" ErrorMessage="* End Date Required" 
                                            Display="Dynamic"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>

                           <br />
                       </div>
                </div>
                  </div>

                   <div class="row">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="col-sm-2"></div>
                    <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="Description">Event Description:</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-8">
                      <asp:TextBox ID="desciptiontxt" runat="server" TextMode="MultiLine" CssClass="form-control" style="width:50%;"  Height="100px" MaxLength="500"></asp:TextBox>
                         <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator18" runat="server" 
                                            ControlToValidate="desciptiontxt" Display="Dynamic" 
                                            ErrorMessage="* Description Required"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                        <br />
                  </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

The above code is for the responsive form layout (grid system). I don't have any idea why Bootstrap breaks formatting of calender.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use z-index property of css to bring the calendar control above all.

For example, if you're using cssclass for calendar as 'Cal' .cal{z-index:99999;} 
this will bring the class with 'Cal' to top.

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me...:)

```
<style type="text/css">
       .ajax__calendar_container { z-index : 1000 ; }
       .ajax__calendar {
        position: relative;
        left: 0px !important;
        top: 0px !important;
        visibility: visible; display: block;
    }
    .ajax__calendar iframe
    {
        left: 0px !important;
        top: 0px !important;
    }
    </style>
```

Answer (score 0):

Tested by adding a TextBox and CalendarExtender to the default VS2013 web forms project.

```
<div class="row">
    <asp:TextBox ID="txtTest" runat="server" />
    <ajaxToolkit:CalendarExtender runat="server" TargetControlID="txtTest" />
</div>
```

may be it helpful!!

Comment: i think this will be other scenario, is it right..!!

Comment: in my case,the calender box is coming under the texbox field of end date and description

Comment: try to make style=position:absolute

Comment: @chandrakant your solution right .@chetan kambli try this style=position:absolute this will may be help..